# C++ compile error with functions

Tags: c++

I was wondering if someone could lend me some advice as to why my code wont compile. I have a simple tic tac toe game here split up into 3 files. Yet, main.cpp is unable to create an objects from my ticTacToe.h file and I just don't understand why. I feel like I'm a step away from getting this to run. ticTacToe.cpp and ticTacToe.h compile just fine. It's the main.cpp file that produces an error when it gets to line 14 "ttt.create_board();". The error message is "unidentified reference to 'ticTacToe: :create_board(char)'" Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks guys.

main.cpp

```
#include "ticTacToe.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <limits> //This is required to catch invalid user input

void run_game()
{
    char letter_o = 'O';
    char letter_x = 'X';
    ticTacToe ttt; //creates an object "ttt" to be used later
    ttt.player1Piece = letter_x;
    ttt.player2Piece = letter_o;
    std::cout << "Welcome to tic tac toe!" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Here is a blank board: " << std::endl;
    ttt.create_board();
    while (true){
        std::cout << "\nPlayer X, it is your turn\n" << std::endl;
        ttt.update_board(letter_x);
        if (ttt.determine_winner(letter_x) == true){
            break;
        }
        std::cout << "\nPlayer O, it is your turn\n" << std::endl;
        ttt.update_board(letter_o);
        if (ttt.determine_winner(letter_o) == true){
            break;
        }
    }
}

int main() //main kicks things off by calling "run_game()"
{
    run_game();

}
```

ticTacToe.h

```
#ifndef TICTACTOE_H
#define TICTACTOE_H


class ticTacToe
{
    public: //Allow us to use the functions anywhere
    char board[3][3]; //Creates an 2d array for the board
    char player1Piece; //variable used in multiple functions
    char player2Piece; //varibable used in multiple

    void create_board();
    void print_board(char playerPiece, int pos1 = 0, int pos2 = 0);
    int check_for_overlap(int pos1, int pos2, char playerPiece);
    void update_board(char playerPiece);
    int determine_winner(char playerPiece);
};

#endif // TICTACTOE_H
```

ticTacToe.cpp

```
#include "ticTacToe.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

ticTacToe::ticTacToe()
{
     void ticTacToe::create_board()
{
    //initializes a blank board
    for(int a = 0; a < 3; a++){
        std::cout << "\n";
        for (int b = 0; b < 3; b++){
            board[a][b] = '-';
            std::cout << board[a][b];
        }
    }
}


void ticTacToe::print_board(char playerPiece, int pos1 = 0, int pos2 = 0)
{
    //prints out the updated board when called upon to do so
    for(int a = 0; a < 3; a++){
        std::cout << "\n";
        for (int b = 0; b < 3; b++){
            board[pos1][pos2] = playerPiece;
            std::cout << board[a][b];
        }
    }
}


int ticTacToe::check_for_overlap(int pos1, int pos2, char playerPiece)
{
    if (board[pos1-1][pos2-1] != '-'){
        std::cout << "\nOVERLAP DETECTED!!!!!!" << std::endl;
        return true;
        }
        return false;
}


void ticTacToe::update_board(char playerPiece)
{
    //updates the board based on user input
    int x, y;
    std::cout << "Enter a position to place the " << playerPiece << " on the board" << std::endl;
    while (true){
        std::cout << "Enter row: " << std::endl;
        std::cin >> x;
        if (x < 1 || x > 3 || std::cin.fail()){
            std::cin.clear();
            std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(),'\n');
            std::cout << "Your number is invalid. Try again. " << std::endl;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }

    while (true)
    {
        std::cout << "Enter col: " << std::endl;
        std::cin >> y;
        if (y < 1 || y > 3 || std::cin.fail()){
            std::cin.clear();
            std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(),'\n');
            std::cout << "Your number is invalid. Try again. " << std::endl;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }

    if (check_for_overlap(x, y, player1Piece) == true){
        x--;y--;print_board(player2Piece, x, y);
        std::cout << "\nThe board has been re-set. Try again!" << std::endl;
    } else if (check_for_overlap(x, y, player2Piece) == true){
        x--;y--;print_board(player1Piece, x, y);
        std::cout << "\nThe board has been re-set. Try again." << std::endl;
    } else {
        x--;y--;print_board(playerPiece, x, y);
    }
}


int ticTacToe::determine_winner(char playerPiece)
{
    /*slices the board and checks if playerPiece occupies that slot.
    If the player makes a line, print that playerPiece has won
    and exit the game.*/
    if (board[0][0] == playerPiece && board[0][1] == playerPiece && board[0][2] == playerPiece){
        std::cout << "\nPlayer " << playerPiece << " wins!" << std::endl;
        return true;
    }
    else if(board[1][0] == playerPiece && board[1][1] == playerPiece && board[1][2] == playerPiece){
        std::cout << "\nPlayer " << playerPiece << " wins!" << std::endl;
        return true;
    }
    else if(board[2][0] == playerPiece && board[2][1] == playerPiece && board[2][2] == playerPiece){
        std::cout << "\nPlayer " << playerPiece << " wins!" << std::endl;
        return true;
    }
    else if(board[0][0] == playerPiece && board[1][0] == playerPiece && board[2][0] == playerPiece){
        std::cout << "\nPlayer " << playerPiece << " wins!" << std::endl;
        return true;
    }
    else if(board[0][1] == playerPiece && board[1][1] == playerPiece && board[2][1] == playerPiece){
        std::cout << "\nPlayer " << playerPiece << " wins!" << std::endl;
        return true;
    }
    else if(board[0][2] == playerPiece && board[1][2] == playerPiece && board[2][2] == playerPiece){
        std::cout << "\nPlayer " << playerPiece << " wins!" << std::endl;
        return true;
    }
    else if(board[0][0] == playerPiece && board[1][1] == playerPiece && board[2][2] == playerPiece){
        std::cout << "\nPlayer " << playerPiece << " wins!" << std::endl;
        return true;
    }
    else if(board[0][2] == playerPiece && board[1][1] == playerPiece && board[2][0] == playerPiece){
        std::cout << "\nPlayer " << playerPiece << " wins!" << std::endl;
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

}

}
```

Comment: Which line produces the error? What is the error?

Comment: ticTacToe.cpp and ticTacToe.h compile just fine. It's the main.cpp file that produces an error when it gets to line 14 "ttt.create_board();". The error message is "unidentified reference to 'ticTacToe: :create_board(char)'"

Comment: smells like a compile and link error. a show the exact error, b - show how you compile and link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply remove both `}` at the very end of `ticTacToe.cpp` and

```
ticTacToe::ticTacToe()
{
```

You didn't declare any constructor in the header file.

Then there is another Problem with the function `print_board`.

It's declared as `void print_board(char playerPiece, int pos1 = 0, int pos2 = 0)` but you're using default arguments in definition, too.

Change both `int pos1=0, int pos2=0` to `int pos1, int pos2` in `ticTacToe.cpp`.

Try to overthink your code formatting to know which bracet belong to which. :)

Comment: I wonder who gave a +1 to this. This answer is wrong. Consider updating. :)

Comment: Whoa that was deffinately an issue, but I still cant get it to compile. Same error message? Were you able to get it to compile?

Comment: @G.Samaras You're right, constructor isn't declared in class.

Comment: It's ok @NaCl. Check the default arguments too, as seen in my answer and I will give you +1, if you update it.

Comment: @YumBerrys, you should accept an answer (of the three made here) if you are happy with one.

Comment: @YumBerrys Consider to upvote and accept G.Samaras answer as he gives some brief explanation why your code does not work at a certain part.

Comment: This is very kind of you NaCl. He doesn't have enough reputation to upvote, so he can only accept an answer (which one, @YumBerrys will show us when he accepts an answer - it's the tick icon next to the answer, on the left).

Answer (score 1):

Change this

```
ticTacToe::ticTacToe()
{
     void ticTacToe::create_board()
{
    //initializes a blank board
    for(int a = 0; a < 3; a++){
        std::cout << "\n";
        for (int b = 0; b < 3; b++){
            board[a][b] = '-';
            std::cout << board[a][b];
        }
    }
}
```

to this

```
void ticTacToe::create_board()
{
    //initializes a blank board
    for(int a = 0; a < 3; a++){
        std::cout << "\n";
        for (int b = 0; b < 3; b++){
            board[a][b] = '-';
            std::cout << board[a][b];
        }
    }
}
```

Then remove from ticTacToe.cpp file the last two curly brackets in the file.

If you want to have a constructor, then you should define it inside the class, like the other functions (and then of course implement it inside .cpp).

```
class ticTacToe {
    ...
    char player2Piece; //varibable used in multiple

    ticTacToe();               <--- HERE
    void create_board();
    void print_board(char playerPiece, int pos1, int pos2); <-- Change the default arguments here
    ...
};
```

Also, in 
`void print_board(char playerPiece, int pos1, int pos2);`
you should not pass the default arguments in the .h file (or the other way around).

Comment: Wait, so are you saying to remove the constructor completely? Instead of default arguments what should it be, blank "()"

Comment: @YumBerrys, either remove the constructor from the .cpp file or write its definition inside your class. For the arguments, leave at the .cpp the signature of the function as seen on my answer and leave the function as is in .h. Better now?

Comment: Thanks for helping me understand what the issue was!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here

```
ticTacToe::ticTacToe()
{
     void ticTacToe::create_board()
     {

     }

     // more functions

}
```

You have wrapped all your member functions inside your tictacToe constructor. As you are not actually doing anything in your constructor you can remove it.

Remove

```
 ticTacToe::ticTacToe()
    {
```

and

```
}
}
```

At the end of your cpp file.

**Also** do not specify default parameters to a method in the method definition (cpp file) and the method declaration (h file).

if you do

```
class ticTacToe
{
public: //Allow us to use the functions anywhere

    ...
    void print_board(char playerPiece, int pos1 = 0, int pos2 = 0);
    ...
};
```

Don't then redeclare the defaults.

```
void ticTacToe::print_board(char playerPiece, int pos1 = 0, int pos2 = 0)
```

Instead declare the method

```
void ticTacToe::print_board(char playerPiece, int pos1, int pos2)
```

A final comment

`check_for_overlap` returns `int`. As you internally use `bool` and check for `bool` when you call it, you should change the method signature to

```
bool ticTacToe::check_for_overlap(int pos1, int pos2, char playerPiece)
```